# How to create tests for serverless testing using Jest for these scenarios?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, jestjs, serverless

I am new to serverless and NodeJS.Could you please guide me how can I create a **automated** test cases for

1. lambda to lambda invoke
2. API Gateway to Lambda Invoke
3. DynamoDB insertion test

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For DynamoDB insertion test, you can install serverless plugins [`serverless-dynamodb-local`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-dynamodb-local) and [`serverless-offline`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline) to create a local DynamoDB to test.

Comment: I want to test using jest that i have already done using serverless offline. I want to write a test case where a lambda invokes another lambda and I get expected rersponse and I pass the unit test

Comment: Automated testing is all i want

Answer (score 3):

If you want full end-to-end test of a lambda function, you will have to handle that outside the function itself.

If you use unit testing tools you will be able to run them locally or even inside the function, but you won't have the ability to actually query the function and go through the whole process.

I'd create a second lambda function with any unit test library, like mocha, and write functional tests that invoke the first lambda function, through API gateway, with a simple http-request package (like request).

**EDIT:**

Here's more clarification on each one of your points:

1) Lambda to lambda invoke

If by lambda-to-lambda you mean you want to call another function WITHOUT using API GW, then I guess you're planning to use the AWS SDK to trigger a function.

If that is the case, it's like any other test. You will create a test function which will get the SDK to trigger the second lambda, and then check the result of the SDK function. It will probably indicate if it's a success or not, or even give you the result.

2) API gateway to lambda invoke

If you are looking to test if the connection between API GW and lambda works, I'd say, why bother? It's a setup-once-and-use kind of deal.. But if you still want to test this, it will be similar to item 1), with the exception that instead of using the SDK, you'd use an API gateway URL.

So you can use an npm package such as axios or request to make a request to such URL and see if the content is the expected.

I'd even say you can run the test in the lambda function and call the very same lambda function, no need to create separate lambdas.

3) Dynamo insertion

This one is the easiest, just create a unit test that writes something into dynamo. Then, in order to know if the test passes or not, just read the DB trying to find what you wrote.

If you're in the fence between testing libraries, I'd suggest going for mocha and chai.

If I can help you answering something more specific, let me know.

Comment: Can you please be detailed?